# create composite index in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create index in mysql in such a way that
Where values of two columns should not be same while they may be same in different rows.

```
+-------------------+------------+-------+
| id                | value 1    |value 2| 
+-------------------+------------+-------+
| id                | 2          | 1     | 
| user_id           | 2          | 1     | 
| following_user_id | 2          | 2     | (value should never like this )
+-------------------+------------+-------+
```

it means values may same in different  rows but not in different columns.
I am talking about value 1 and value 2.

Comment: Why not just specify a unique index for the columns?

Comment: If i specify for colum then it  should not allow same value in multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with an index since that works on different rows and not checking columns in a single row.

You could use a check constraint in other DB engines but MySQL does currently ignore that.

Use a trigger that checks the values and aborts the insertion/update if they are incorrect. For an update you can use something like this

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER your_update_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.value1 = NEW.value2 THEN 
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred. Same IDs are not allowed';
    END IF;
END
|
delimiter ;
```

Comment: how can i add that trigger?

Comment: IF i apply trigger then is there any effect on performance. I will use it if and only if it does not slow down my query.

Comment: I doubt there is a measurable difference. But you can try it and see.